# Display an Alert with Text Field Entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert

How to display a text entry field in an alert to get input from the user and use that input back in the application (display the input on a label ) ?

As showing below
[image]
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Text"
                                                                message:@"Enter some text below"
                                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *submit = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                   if (alert.textFields.count > 0) {

                                                       UITextField *textField = [alert.textFields firstObject];

                                                       textField.text // your text
                                                   }

                                               }];

[alert addAction:submit];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"something"; // if needs
}];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

To add TextField to `UIAlertView` set `alertViewStyle` property with `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                message:@"Message"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

In .h file add UIAlertViewDelegate as a protocol and implement the delegate method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex` in the .m file.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
}
```